Invalid int error for array field with str associated with ints
I keep getting this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        def encrypt(file):
            encrypt = " "
            with open("test.txt","r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
                    count = int((lines[i]))
                    word = lines[i + 1].strip()
                    encrypt += word[:count] + " "
            return encrypt.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print(" ")
        encrypted_string = encrypt("test.txt")
        print(encrypted_string)

        [print("hello world")]

I understand that this error means that the string being associated with the int could be parsed. How do I fix it?

The error (exception) simply means that you're trying to convert something to int that cannot be represented as an integer. The exception you show is incomplete. The actual exception will tell you what the erroneous value is. If you explain exactly what your program is hoping to achieve you may get additional help

The issue is that you're trying to convert each line in the file to an integer, but some lines may not contain valid integers.
You can use isdigit() method of the string, which returns True if the string consists of digits only.
if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    def encrypt(file):
        encrypt = ""
        with open("test.txt","r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
                if lines[i].strip().isdigit():  # Check if the line contains a valid integer
                    count = int(lines[i].strip())
                    word = lines[i + 1].strip()
                    encrypt += word[:count] + " "
                else:
                    print(f"Warning: Invalid integer found on line {i + 1}: {lines[i]}")
        return encrypt.strip()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    print(" ")
    encrypted_string = encrypt("test.txt")
    print(encrypted_string)

    [print("hello world")]


str.isdigit() is not reliable in this context. Better to attempt the conversion and handle any exception. For example, "\u00B2".isdigit() == True but int("\u00B2") will raise a ValueError exception
